# Binding a key in another package's yet undefined map in use-package?

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, use-package

I'm using `use-package` for my configuration in `init.el`.
How can I bind a key to a map that has not yet been defined?

As a specific example, I'm using the following configuration of

```lisp
(use-package latex-mode
  :ensure auctex
  :mode "\\.tex\\'" "\\.sty\\'")
```

I'm also using the `citar` package for LaTeX and Org bibliographies:

```lisp
(use-package citar
  :hook ((LaTeX-mode org-mode) . citar-capf-setup)
  :bind (:map LaTeX-mode-map ("C-c [" . #'citar-insert-citation)))
```

Unfortunately, if I open an `.org` file first, I get the following error: "File mode specification error: (void-variable LaTeX-mode-map)".

Within the `use-package` framework, what is the correct way to resolve this error?  I could always hook the keybinding into `LaTeX-mode-hook`, but I'm wondering if there is a `use-package`-based solution?

**EDIT:**  Here is a minimal `init.el` that produces the above error if I first open a `.org` file before opening a `.tex` file.

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/"))

(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-and-compile
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t
        use-package-expand-minimally t))

;; LaTeX mode and citar

(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex)

(use-package citar
  :hook ((LaTeX-mode org-mode) . citar-capf-setup)
  :bind (:map LaTeX-mode-map ("C-c [" . #'citar-insert-citation)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT In response to @Tyler's comments here, and his answer and the comments there

After looking again at [the 'Binding to local keymaps' section](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#binding-to-local-keymaps) of the use-package documentation, I now understand that that method should only be used for keymaps defined in the package getting declared. Therefore, I would suggest that the cleanest solution (i.e. deferred and without any errors) is to simply load the latex package as follows:

```lisp
(use-package latex
  :ensure auctex
  :ensure citar
  :hook ((LaTeX-mode org-mode) . citar-capf-setup)
  :bind (:map LaTeX-mode-map ("C-c [" . citar-insert-citation)))
```

That we can use the `:ensure` keyword twice was found by trial and error combined with `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`.
Of course [`:defer` is implied by using `:hook` and/or `:bind`](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#hook).

SECOND EDIT In response to question in the comments

The

```lisp
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex)
```

could be considered 'arbitrary' and 'undesired'; arbitrary because any of the files that provides a 'feature' could have been used, and 'undesired' because it makes the 'tex.el' file load immediately (not deferred). It is really only used for installing auctex, but use-package/require can only declare libraries that provide a feature, and the author of the documentation has arbitrarily chosen the `tex` package in order to install via `use-package`. You could also just install via `package-install` and the 'auctex' package will load fine.
The only auctex file that has got to be loaded immediately is `tex-site.el(c)`, but that is taken care of by using the autoload mechanism to 'require it' (see the `auctex-autoloads.el` file)

The `:bind` section is executed after loading the declared package. Because `LaTeX-mode-map` is defined in the `latex.el` file, it is not yet defined after loading `tex.el`. As the only way to load the definition is by loading `latex.el`, we simply declare 'latex' so that it is loaded when the `:bind` section gets executed.

END EDIT

The `latex-mode-map` exists already on Emacs startup. Just downcase the full name `LaTeX-mode-map` to `latex-mode-map`, and your use-package declaration should work fine. You should also downcase `LaTeX-mode` to `latex-mode` in the `:hook` keyword.

Additionally, `latex-mode` is defined in the `tex-mode` mode library, so your first `use-package` declaration should declare `tex-mode` instead of `latex-mode`.

`"\\.tex\\'"` and `"\\.sty\\'"` are already included in the `auto-mode-alist` by default, so you can remove that `:mode` keyword from the `tex-mode` declaration. Your `.tex` documents will be opened in `latex-mode` as long as your `tex-default-mode` is set to `latex-mode` (the default).

In case you would have to add `latex-mode` via the `:mode` keyword in the `tex-mode` declaration, then you can find in [the ':mode' section of the use-package documentation](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#mode-interpreter) how to do that.

Finally, in case the latex-mode-map had not been defined yet, as far as I understand from [the 'Binding to local keymaps' section in the use-package documentation](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#binding-to-local-keymaps), using the `:map` keyword in the `:bind` section should automatically defer defining the keybinding until the tex-mode package got loaded. I don't see a (sharp-)quote in that documentation, so let's remove it.

In the end, the following should be correct declarations:

```lisp
(use-package tex-mode
  :ensure auctex)

(use-package citar
  :hook ((latex-mode org-mode) . citar-capf-setup)
  :bind (:map latex-mode-map ("C-c [" . citar-insert-citation)))
```

Comment: `latex-mode` and `LaTeX-mode` are not the same thing. The first is part of Emacs, defined in `tex-mode.el`, and the second is part of AucTeX, defined in `latex.el` in that package.

Comment: Thanks! I am not using AUCTeX at the moment, so I did not notice that indeed.

Comment: it can be very confusing, but these libraries are very old and the names are stuck now!

Comment: I've added a (what I think is the) correct and cleanest solution.

Comment: Thanks!  The code from your edit does indeed work the way I'd like.  One thing still puzzles me however.  The AUCTeX manual does indeed suggest `(use-package tex :ensure auctex)`, but I was not able to get your code to work with `use-package tex`.  I had to use `use-package latex` (which is what you have).  Do you have any idea why there is this discrepancy with the AUCTeX manual?  It's not a big deal; I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with this code:

```lisp
(use-package latex-mode
  :ensure auctex
  :mode "\\.tex\\'" "\\.sty\\'")
```

`latex-mode` is the built-in LaTeX mode for Emacs, which is not the same as `LaTeX-mode` provided by the `AucTeX` package. If you want to use the AucTeX version, this section will over-ride your intentions, and directs Emacs to use `latex-mode` for `tex` files.

It's probably not necessary at all, but if you want to use `use-package` as part of your AucTeX config, the recommended code (from the manual) is:

```lisp
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex)
```

After you remove the problematic first section, the second section should work as you expect (it does for me, with AucTeX and citar both installed via the package system):

```lisp
(use-package citar
  :hook ((LaTeX-mode org-mode) . citar-capf-setup)
  :bind (:map LaTeX-mode-map ("C-c [" . #'citar-insert-citation)))
```

If you want to use the non-AucTeX version, `latex-mode`, make sure to use this version (i.e., all lower case) in your `:hook` and `:bind` arguments.

Comment: The `:bind` here does not work when visiting an org buffer first, because latex.el then has not been loaded yet. Now as the binding is added to the LaTeX-mode-map, we can just add it via `:config` and a `(with-eval-after-load 'latex ...`, however, the `:config` block here, for some weird reason, only gets called when visiting an org file, but not when visiting a tex file, even though the 'hook' runs successfully for both. So then we can add it via the `:init` keyword, in which case it finally works correctly.

Comment: @dalanicolai ah, I missed the part about visiting an org file first, I only tested on a .tex file! thanks

Comment: @dalanicolai after testing, it 'works' without error for me when opening an org file? Can you or Henry/OP provide the steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Tyler and @dalanicolai I've attached a minimal `init.el` that produces the error if I open an `.org` file before opening a `.tex` file.

Comment: @dalanicolai @Tyler Yes, I could certainly do something with `with-eval-after-load` as dalanicolai suggests, but I was hoping that there would be a more paradigmatic `use-package` solution.

Comment: @HenryDeYoung how does the error present itself? When you open the org file, when you open the tex file, when you type `C-c [`? I can't reproduce it on Emacs 30.0.50. WAIT: I do get an error, in the *Messages* buffer, but it doesn't impact the keybinding when I open the tex file.

Comment: @Tyler Yes, in the `*Messages*` buffer when opening a `.org` file.  And if I later open a `.tex` file, the keybinding is not set up.  Also, I'm using Emacs 29.1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dalanicolai's suggestion of two `:ensure`s, I realized that `use-package citar` could be split in two, with the `:bind` with `LaTeX-mode-map` being guarded by `:after latex` (and not the more permissive `:after (:any latex org)`).  This seems to work correctly for me.

```lisp
(use-package latex
  :ensure auctex
  :mode ("\\.tex\\'" . LaTeX-mode))

(use-package citar
  :after (:any latex org)
  :hook ((LaTeX-mode org-mode) . citar-capf-setup))

(use-package citar
  :after latex
  :bind (:map LaTeX-mode-map ("C-c [" . citar-insert-citation)))
```

The inclusion of `:mode ("\\.tex\\'" . LaTeX-mode)` is necessary to defer loading of AUCTeX until a `.tex` buffer is created.  It may also be possible to replace this with `:defer` because, as @dalanicolai pointed out, `"\\.tex\\'"` is among `auto-mode-alist`.